# Auto refresh in jquery

Tags: jquery

I used this code for refresh my div in my page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

setInterval("my_function();",2000); 
    function my_function(){
      $('#show').load(location.href + ' #show');

    }
}
</script>
```

But only one time it refreshing,after that not.If there is any error on this code.Please guide me.

Comment: i need to refresh every 2 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually passing the function but executing it. Try something like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function my_function(){
    $('#show').load(location.href + ' #show');
}
setInterval(my_function, 2000); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`setInterval(function, milliseconds)`
 repeats the execution of the function continuously.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
   $('#show').load(location.href + ' #show');
}, 2000);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urfusion/857j7Ld1/)

Comment: check your console for any error after the first refresh.